# Java - Adding elements to a new list after going through 2 or more for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

So this code is just one I made quickly and is not my actual code but I am trying to add specific values from one list to another list after going through two `for loops` and a few `if statements`.

**Example Code**

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
//example list [0, 20, 10, 9, 11, 7, 9, 14]

List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (i=0; i < intList.size()-1; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j < intList.size(); j++) {
        if (intList.get(j) > intList.get(i)) {
            result.add(intList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
system.out.println(result);
```

**Expected Result**

```
[0, 9, 7, 9]
```

So in this case, I want to have just 4 values in my list, however since I am going through the list multiple times through the 2 `for loops` I end up getting multiple repeats of the same values being added to the list (something like `[0,0,0,0,0,9,9,9,7,7,9]`).
How do I fix this without removing repeated values, since using that would result in removing the second 9 from the list too.

Comment: Why do you need 2 for loops here?

Comment: I think you're logic is quite confusing what exactly are you trying to do? Storing indexes or the actual values of lists? Also try using a Set<Integer> instead of a List<Integer> result to avoid storing repeated values.

Comment: What is the logic you want to use in fetching the specific numbers from the list? Its not clear.

Comment: This specific code, I wanted to grab the values where the one right after it was greater (0 < 20 so add 0 to the list). Its a dumbed down version of my actual code which contains both strings and ints and utilises regex's to compare between the elements to sort into multiple lists depending on what's next to it. Sorry for the trouble I've caused and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are comparing the indices of the array.
You want to compare the values of the array at the respective indices.

You only need one loop and you need to guard against an out of bounds by making sure `i` is not the last index.

```
for (int i=0; i < intList.size()-1; i++) {
    if (intList.get(i+1) > intList.get(i)) {
        result.add(intList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: so sorry! yes I have the correct code like you mentioned in my main code (though i'm using `List.get(i)`) but my main problem is that since I am going through the loop multiple times with `j`, I am getting the same values being added multiple times.

Comment: You don't need the inner for loop. Remove it and check `i+1` for each iteration.

Comment: thank you! I've removed the inner loop and checked and my problem has indeed been solved. Would you be able to give me a quick explanation of why one would use a nested loop? Since I have indeed been mistaking things.

Comment: @DanielCanas 1) intList[i] does not work, 2) You don't need the (i != intList.size()-1) condition, 3) you are not declaring the i varaible

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Yeah. You're right about `intList[i]`... Thinking in Python

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis You need to make sure intList its at least `size()-2` so you don't go over the array size when you check `intList.get(i+1)`

Comment: @DanielCanas No you don't, since you are going to i < intList.size()-1 in the for loop

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis +1 missed that. Yeah, we don't need to get to end of the array, we can stop iterating at `size()-1` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if I Understood the problem statement you are comparing pair value i.e 0, 20 for first iteration and 10, 9 for second one so you need to add break statement to avoid duplicates and increment i value for comaparing next pair value

```
   List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

    //example list [0, 20, 10, 9, 11, 7, 9, 14]

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i < intList.size()-1; i++) {

        for (int j=i+1; j < intList.size(); j++) {

            if (intList.get(j) > intList.get(i)) {
                result.add(intList.get(i));                 
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Why would you do this with 2 for loops?

Comment: So in this example, it's 'breaking' away from the inner loop if it satisfies the condition, and then increasing the index value so regardless of whether `if` is true or false, it will always prevent j from going to j+1?